# Form nested list to network object

Tags: r, networking, nested

I have a nested list, I want to create a network object where being present in a sub-list constitute a link.

```
tmp <- list(c("A","B","C"), c("B","D"), c("B"))
```

Expected result:

```
netmat1 <- rbind(c(0,1,1,0), c(1,0,1,1), c(1,1,0,0),c(0,1,0,0))
rownames(netmat1) <- c("A","B","C","D") 
colnames(netmat1) <- c("A","B","C","D")
```

Creating a network object, in the edge list format might be simple.
That would imply divide each element of `tmp` into unique couples (unordered), and dropping the single elements:

```
tmp_prime <- list(c(A,B),c(A,C),c(A,C),c(B,D))
net <- network(tmp_prime,matrix.type="edgelist")
```

Any help welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this work for you:

```
library(network)
x <- do.call(cbind, lapply(tmp[lengths(tmp) > 1], combn, 2))
net <- network(t(x), matrix.type = 'edgelist', directed = F)

# > as.matrix(net)
#   A B C D
# A 0 1 1 0
# B 1 0 1 1
# C 1 1 0 0
# D 0 1 0 0
```

`lapply(tmp[lengths(tmp) > 1], combn, 2)` will create edges for each list elements with at least 2 values. `do.call(cbind, ...)` will bind all the edges in two a single matrix (each column is an edge). Below is how `t(x)` looks like:

```
# > t(x)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "A"  "B" 
# [2,] "A"  "C" 
# [3,] "B"  "C" 
# [4,] "B"  "D"
```

Then you can get an undirected network with `network` from the `network` package easily. I am not so familiar with `network` package. There might be simpler solutions.